# Geolocation and GeoIP alternative

Tags: php, jquery, blackberry, gps

What alternatives are there for GEOIP and HTML 5 Geolocation that are more accurate and are able to work reliably on BlackBerry browsers?

Comment: This depends on your needs, but I don't think you'll find anything.  Those are your best methods, short of asking the user where they are.  Perhaps if you could tell us more about what you are wanting to do, we could provide a better solution.

Comment: All is fine on each computer browsers because I only need to get the country not the exact city of the clients.The only problem is the blackberry and other browsers I am having a hard time fixing the real location on blackberry browser even the GPS on blackberry is lat/long is (0,0).

Answer (score 2):

You could look into IP2Location. However, if you're worried about accuracy, you shouldn't expect high percentages from free services. Even the pay services aren't heads and shoulders above the free ones and will always have `< 100%` accuracy. That's just the nature of the beast. I've heard many instances where folks inside the UK can't watch BBC online because their ip is incorrectly found to be outside of the country.

Some geo ip services: Akamai, Quova, Digital Envoy (digital element), Google (javascript), Maxmind (which you've used), hostip.info, Geobytes, ip2location, ip geo.

Comment: All is fine on each computer browsers because I only need to get the country not the exact city of the clients.The only problem is the blackberry and other browsers I am having a hard time fixing the real location on blackberry browser even the GPS on blackberry is lat/long is (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing geo-location based on the IP address of the request coming in to your web server, it's not going to be accurate.  Anyone using BIS to browse the web (i.e. any consumer device not on BES or Wi-Fi) is proxied through RIM's servers in Canada - so all requests will appear to be coming from Canada.

Comment: its not going to be actuate if the user is using a proxy, and lots of times its impossible to match up an ip to an exact location.

Answer (score 0):

The Geolocation API should be pretty accurate if you set enableHighAccuracy. It's still up to the browser and device to interpret that, though. Is this feature not available on the BlackBerry browser you're targetting? GPS can take a while to lock on to a satellite...have you tried using watchPosition() and just letting it run for awhile as a test?

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
unserialize(file_get_contents('http://www.geoplugin.net/php.gp?ip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
```