# Other ways to get the location of the visitor on your site?

Tags: php, jquery, mobile, geolocation, gps

I have tried HTML 5 geolocation,GEOIP and many other services.But it is still not good.Even I only need to get the country of the visitors.

Comment: Why is it still not good? Identifying the IP should give you the country fairly accurately in most cases.

Comment: Yes, I've found it fairly good (just using GeoLite Country) -- you might want to give examples of IPs and countries that you're having problems with...

Comment: You already asked this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736661/geolocation-and-geoip-alternative/4736736#4736736

Answer (score 0):

IMO the best way is to use GEOIP, you can also get the free city database if you want to drill down the location further.  I wrote a simple class that works with apache's mod_geoip as well as instructions on how to install the module and geoip databases. It's on [GitHub](http://github.com/jbusby/JB_GeoIP)  if you want to take a look.

Comment: Why would you write a 367 line wrapper to replace the single line of code to print any of those values in native PHP once mod_geoip is installed? `<?php echo apache_note("GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE"); ?>`

Comment: In a word, encapsulation.  The class I put on github is a paired down version of one we use with our platform.  You're right though, if you want to access the geoip info quickly your method works great, so would <?php echo $_SERVER["GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE"]; ?>, however in our case this would have created a lot of duplicate code.